# Why does agetty ask for the username itself?

Tags: login, getty

From the man page:

> agetty opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes  the  /bin/login  command.  It  is  normally  invoked  by init(8).

But if you run login without any argument, it asks a username. So why not let login do the job of asking the username, instead of doing it inside agetty (also, if your login fails, *login* will ask you your username again)?

It just seems redundant to me. I thought agetty's only job would be to call login repeatedly (because login exits after a certain number of tries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reading in the username, `agetty` can automatically adapt the tty settings like parity bits, character size, and newline processing. If you disable it (`--skip-login` options), it needs to assume (possibly wrong) default settings.